# Jersey + Spring deployment failure on Glassfish : CDI issue

Tags: spring, jersey-2.0, weld

I'm tryng to setup a Glassfish + Spring configuration. Please find below the relevant part of my pom :

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0M10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have an issue with the following dependency :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

When I specify this dependency as provided, deployment is OK.. but SPring context isn't initialized. If I comment the `provided` element, then sometimes deployment is OK and the application is running fine, but sometimes deplyment will fail and I will get following WELD-001408 exception :

```
    [2014-12-16T10:21:07.618+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1418721667618] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<DefaultTopicDistributionErrorService>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.glassfish.hk2.internal.DefaultTopicDistributionService.errorHandlers]
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<DefaultTopicDistributionErrorService>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.glassfish.hk2.internal.DefaultTopicDistributionService.errorHandlers]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:325)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:208)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:519)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:505)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:480)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:216)
    ... 36 more
]]
```

I've seen many issues regarding this, but I still don't get what is the right way to go...
What I want is a REST API built with Jersey, with the benefits of Spring CDI (ideally no xml spring config).

What should I modify in my POM to make it work ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably victim of this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-377

I'm just guessing since you didn't provide the version of Glassfish you are using.
This issue has been fixed in CDI 1.2 which is included in Glassfish 4.1. So the best solution would be to update to this version.

If you can't or don't want to update you can use this workaround: http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#4

Comment: Yeah I saw this answer on another thread. Server upgrade isn't an option. I tested locally though, and that seems to fix the issue. I guess I'll try the workaround for now...