# CDI deployment failure:WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous - jar issue

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish, openstack

I'm getting started with OpenStack4j and have problems right at the beginning. I've got such error while deploying:

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name JerseyClassAnalyzer resolves to beans: [Managed Bean [class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any], Managed Bean [class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:234)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
```

I've read [Jersey + Spring deployment failure on Glassfish : CDI issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501393/jersey-spring-deployment-failure-on-glassfish-cdi-issue) and [CDI deployment failure:WELD-001414 Bean name is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050266/cdi-deployment-failureweld-001414-bean-name-is-ambiguous)
but I'm working on Glassfish 4.1, don't have any more dependencies with jersey except OpenStack4j and I can't give `<scope>provided</scope>` for this dependency of course.

That's my all dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pacesys</groupId>
        <artifactId>openstack4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <classifier>withdeps</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20151123</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
        <version>5.3</version>  
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I do have the same problem but a bit change in technologies. I am using EJB. Let me know if any solution you found.